# MySQL query to join more than 3 tables takes way too long

Tags: php, mysql

I have about 20 tables, all of them has the same structure as follows:

```
id |    date    | received_calls|answered_calls
---|----------------------------------------
 1 | 2016-11-10 |     2151      | 2021         |   
 2 | 2016-11-11 |     5201      | 5121         |
 3 | 2016-11-12 |     3333      | 2930         |
```

what i'm trying to do is sum `section1.received_calls` + `section2.received_calls` + `section3.received_calls`.....(with some formulas as shown on code)...etc at the date of X
and the same again.. in the next row, for the next day date.
and so on.
the dates are unique per table and in daily order and cannot be duplicated.

my code is:

```
SELECT
`section1`.date AS date,
(
    `section1`.received_calls + `section2`.received_calls + `section3`.received_calls
) AS received_calls,
(
    `section1`.answered_calls + `section2`.answered_calls + `section3`.answered_calls
) AS answered_calls,
ROUND(
    (
        `section1`.answered_calls + `section2`.answered_calls + `section3`.answered_calls
    ) / (
        `section1`.received_calls + `section2`.received_calls + `section3`.received_calls
    ) * (100),2) AS ans_calls,
(
    `section1`.Abandoned_Calls + `section2`.Abandoned_Calls + `section3`.Abandoned_Calls
) AS Abandoned_Calls,
ROUND(
    (
        `section1`.abandoned_calls + `section2`.abandoned_calls + `section3`.abandoned_calls
    ) / (
        `section1`.received_calls + `section2`.received_calls + `section3`.received_calls
    ) * (100),2) AS aban_calls,
ROUND(
    (
        `section1`.`Avg_Speed_Ans` + `section2`.`Avg_Speed_Ans` + `section3`.`Avg_Speed_Ans`
    ) / (
        `section1`.received_calls + `section2`.received_calls + `section3`.received_calls
    ) * (100),2) AS `Avg_Speed_Ans`
FROM
    `section1`
JOIN `section2` ON `section1`.date = `section2`.date,
 `section3`
GROUP BY
    `section1`.date
```

The problem is that it's working fine, but VERY VERY slow, it can take up 3 hours to complete (and every table has less than 800 row), and I've indexed already the columns i'm using above. and have a primary key set to ID column for each table.

Comment: It looks like your join conditions are not explicit enough. Joining all records from 3 tables for 1 date by joining on date alone (I'm assuming you have> 1 record per day in each table) will cause a Cartesian.

Comment: For instance: assume you have 5 records per day per table, your query is going to return 125 records per day. You can't see them because you're summing and grouping by date, but that's what is happening i think.

Comment: Thanks jeff for you concern and reply :) .. the problem is the slowness of processing. after i wait.. for whatever that long period is, I can see my results fine. is there anyway to boost this up a bit? :(

Comment: A Cartesian will not only provide indirect data but also slow down your query.

Comment: Incorrect* data i meant to say

Comment: WHY do you have 20 tables with the exact same structure. _Database design error, almost definitely_ ___You reap what you sow___

Comment: Because every table has the date regarding separate section. so every section has his own received calls, answered calls, abandoned calls...etc. that's why I didn't merge them all together. If you have a suggestion, you are more than welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have about 20 tables, all of them has the same structure as follows

Your database is not normalized - the first fail.

Did you read any of the *many* questions here about query performance? Did you note the comments, which ones were upvoted, which were downvoted?

You have not provided the indexes for the tables, you have not provided the explain plan for the query. You have not provided the cardinality of the attributes you use in the join.

> can take up 3 hours to complete (and every table has less than 800 row)

This rather implies that the date attribute is not unique, and even after 3 hours, the result you get is wrong - its a partial cartesian product.

This will be much faster and give you a valid answer:

```
SELECT `date`, SUM(answered_calls), SUM(received_calls)
, SUM(abandoned_calls), /* add in your formulas.... */
FROM
(
SELECT `date`, answered_calls, received_calls, abandoned_calls
FROM section1
UNION ALL
SELECT `date`, answered_calls, received_calls, abandoned_calls
FROM section2
UNION ALL
SELECT `date`, answered_calls, received_calls, abandoned_calls
FROM section3
) AS ilv
GROUP BY ilv.`date`
```

However this gives you the right answer to the wrong question. It should be constrained by date range, as well as only using a single table.

Comment: regarding your question.. if i've read the questions about query performance or i've just gone with the EASY way out by posing here, well. I DID, that's why I mentioned that I indexed the used columns, and also. I designed the DB that way, because as you can see. every section has it's own volume of calls. that's why I didn't merge them all together... also. (This rather implies that the date attribute is not unique) the dates are unique per table as I said. first row starts at 1-1-2014 till 11-11-2016. so it's impossible to have duplicates.

Comment: And by the way.. Thanks for your help though it was mixed with a little bit of fury :) . the code is working fine, and executes in less than a second.

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking the tables out into subqueries. For Example:

```
Select t.date, t.calls + u.calls + v.calls allcalls from (select date, sum(calls) as calls from table1 where date=dateiwant group by date) as t ,
(select date, sum(calls) as calls from table2 where date=dateiwant group by date) as u ,
(select date, sum(calls) as calls from table3 where date=dateiwant group by date) as v
Where t.date = u.date
And u.date = v.date
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, worked fine! :) but I guess I will be going with the other code posted here as it seems less confusing :) ... thanks again for your help bud.